# spark ssc.textFileStream is not streamining new files

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to stream from an hdfs folder (sparkstreamining)
I tried:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("spark://quickstart.cloudera:7077")
            .setAppName("BigData");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = 
              new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));


    ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://user/cloudera/events/")
```

In order to check if it is the good folder I did

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

I'm not getting any error by the return JavaDStream is not containing any data.
The folder is allready containing some files..

Is there any other method to check the folder path?
Are there any other things that I should check?

**Note:** I also tried to read from a local file and put it then in a stream, but I still have an empty input (here is the code for this trial).I checked the location of the file that is on my pc with the spark-shell..The input.print() line is giving an java.io.Exception...

```
   System.out.println( "Create context(es)" );
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("spark://quickstart.cloudera:7077")
        .setAppName("BigData")
        .setSparkHome("/usr/lib/spark")
        .setJars(new String[]{"target/standard-to-self-explicit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"});
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);   
    SparkConf sparkConf2 = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("spark://quickstart.cloudera:7077")
    .setAppName("BigData2")
    .setJars(new String[]{"target/standard-to-self-explicit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"});
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf2, new Duration(2000));



    System.out.println( "Set input file" );

    JavaRDD<String> inputRDD1 = sc.textFile(inputFile+"1.json");
    JavaRDD<String> inputRDD2 = sc.textFile(inputFile+"2.json");
    Queue<JavaRDD<String>> inputRDDQueue = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<String>>();
    inputRDDQueue.add(inputRDD1);
    inputRDDQueue.add(inputRDD2);
    System.out.println("debug 1: "+(String)inputRDD1.toDebugString());
    //System.out.println("first 1: "+inputRDD1.take(3).toString());
    JavaDStream<String> input = ssc.queueStream(inputRDDQueue);
    input.print();
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Also The logs from this second version are showing that there is a problem with the input:

```
RROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1416306522000 ms.1
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 14.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 14.0 (TID 78, quickstart.cloudera): **java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type**
        java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1538)
        java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1025)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
```

Thank you!

Comment: The last time this happened to me it was because I had forgotten to call `ssc.start()`.

Comment: I think I'm dealing with multiple errors. I added ssc.start() and ssc.awaitTermination() and the file is still empty...

Comment: How do you know that `JavaDStream is not containing any data`? Could you paste the codes?

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `textFileStream`: "Create a input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem for *new* files and reads them as text files (using key as LongWritable, value as Text and input format as TextInputFormat). Files must be written to the monitored directory by *"moving"* them from another location within the same file system. File names starting with . are ignored." I don't think your pre-existing files will be delivered, and you need to _move_ some files into the directory. Are you doing that?

Comment: Since I posted I changed the code in order to try to read from 2 local files (still empty input). Since I cannot post as many characters in the comment, I will upgrade my post in order to add all my current code.

Comment: @zsxwing I know that the JavaDStream is not containing any code because I run with the debugger in eclipse and the table was empty and the size of it 0.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov I tried to respect that in 2 ways: firstly I putted some files in the folder (not happening anything). Than I manually added some files(I copyed them with the Hue interface) while debugging in eclipse.